# CSS corner radius reveals background color?

Tags: css

CSS border radius works fine, but it's now revealing a white background. (I'd prefer transparent or grey, similar to body background...)

[image: problematic rounded corners...]

CSS:

```
.window_header{
    width:600px;
    height:42px;
    background: #333 url("../img/bg-2.png") repeat;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),inset 0 -4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),inset 1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),inset -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),inset 0 2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15),inset -2px 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15),inset 2px 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
```

Comment: Please post a prototype showing the issue on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The white should be from the background of the container "behind" the one you applied border-radius to.
Maybe try to apply border-radius to it as well.

Comment: Maybe "instead" rather than "as well"

Comment: ah, that was it! I was using a wrapper div for layout purposes...rounded that one too and now it looks great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend either applying Border Radius to the underlying Element so instead of having rough white edges, the element would have rounded corners. So you wouldn't see the white edges.

-or-

Place the whole element edit before the containing element so it sits on top of the white background and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the bg-2 file isn't transparent in that area? Depending on the editor that you used to create the image, it may not have had the ability to make it transparent.

Max Gherkins's explanation is also a very big possibility. :)

Comment: I checked that, but no dice. Looks like I needed to round the parent layout div. Thanks for looking anyway!

Answer (score 0):

background: #333 url("../img/bg-2.png") repeat;

Your background image is not transparent. If it is a "flattened PNG", make sure the background is "transparent" and not "white".

Comment: I checked that, but no dice. Looks like I needed to round the parent layout div. Thanks for looking anyway!